# Overflow in CSS not working in data table

Tags: html, css

When I want to display large amount of data in the table, the text in the cell gets cut off.

In order to get it fixed, I tried to use `overflow-x:auto` but seems not working.

What I have now, (bootstrap ver 3.3.6)

```
    <div class="box" style="overflow-x: auto; height: 90%">
          <div class="box-header">
            <div style="font-size: 18px;">TABLE</div>
          </div>
              <div class="box-body">
                <table id="test" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="overflow-x:auto;">...</td> // Here is what I tried with overflow
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Here is my CSS

```
.table {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.table-responsive {
  min-height: .01%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
```

It seems data table holds not all data.

Any ideas how to get it fixed?

Comment: try to give a width to that td

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but thead should contain th cells and tbody should contain td cells.

Comment: @MatteoZanini do you mean giving a width without overflow?

Comment: @PoulBak seems not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set table-layout: fixed; inside your css for your table selector and also add overflow: hidden; to the table data to make text-overflow work.

```
.table {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  table-layout: fixed; <<<< add this
}

td {
  overflow: hidden; <<<<< and this
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-7qwgts?file=style.css)